# US visa passport is not matching with Indian passport

Tags: visas

I am an Indian citizen. My given name on the Indian passport is Myneni Jyothika and I don't have a surname so it's blank. Now in my US F1 visa, under given name it shows FNU and for the surname it shows Myneni Jyothika. Will that be a problem and if it is how should I correct it as I am already in the USA?

Thank you.